# How To Target Only Second Element of Paper (Image or Rectangle) in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, raphael

eUsing Raphael.js 2.1.0 I am trying to add two background image to the paper object like:

```
var w = 794;
var h = 680;
var map = Raphael("canvas");
      map.image('http://1.png', 0, 0, 794, 680);
      map.image('http://2.png', 0, 0, 794, 680);
```

Or

```
var w = 794;
var h = 680;
var map = Raphael("canvas");
map.rect(0,0, 794, 680).attr({
                              fill: "url(http://1.png)"
});
map.rect(0,0, 794, 680).attr({
                              fill: "url(http://2.png)"
});
```

now I need to find a way to enable user to change ONLY the second background image (from image() or fill:) by changing a Select option list of images but I do not know how to target  the second background using jQuery or JavaScript.

Can you please let me know how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Not quite sure I'm seeing the problem, can't you just use var image2 = map.image('http://2.png', 0, 0, 794, 680); // do something with image2 ?

Comment: Hi lan, and thanks for reply. You are right I used your your hint to refrencing the images. Here is a sample : http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/22WJ3/1/ BUT there are some issues here: 1- First of all the Function is not replacing the image , in fact it is adding( overlaying) a new image still with name image2! ---2- This also cause the svg hides under the newly added image so the hover function not working! can you please let me know how I can REPLACE image 2 with new image without affecting on hover function and of course removing the previous image2 from canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few bits to get to the point mentioned in the comment.

You need to reference the image2, and then you will need to remove() it. So your click function would look something like this...

```
$("#change").on("click",function(){
    image2.remove();
    image2  = map.image('myimageurl.png', 0, 0, 500, 500).insertBefore( circle );
});
```

Note the .insertBefore( element ) function thats used. This will put the element behind the circle, so the hover will still work.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22WJ3/3/)